# XPath: locate an element with text nodes containing two strings

Tags: html, xpath

I want to use XPath to locate a div (class="class1") element which encapsulates both strings 'Text1' and 'Text2' in this html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="class1">
        <div>
            <a href="http://url1.com">Text1</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <a href="http://url2.com">Text2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="class1">
        <div>
            <a href="http://url3.com">Text3</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <a href="http://url4.com">Text4</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But this xpath does not seem to work:

```
//div[@class="class1" and contains(text(),"Text1") and contains(text(),"Text2")]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `text()`, as it's related only to the immediate text children of the node:

```
//div[@class="class1" and contains(., "Text1") and contains(., "Text2")]
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you. That works perfectly and makes sense.